# After grouping calculate the sum of first 3 occurance of node using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How to calculate the sum of first 3 occurance of the value the hour node after  grouping by empid and date in the below xml and store the total in a variable.

```
<Records>
    <Line>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Date>10/01/2012</Date>
      <Hour>4</Hour>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Date>10/01/2012</Date>
      <Hour>4</Hour>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Date>10/02/2012</Date>
      <Hour>8</Hour>
    </Line>
     <Line>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Date>10/03/2012</Date>
      <Hour>8</Hour>
    </Line>
     <Line>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Date>10/04/2012</Date>
      <Hour>8</Hour>
    </Line>
  </Records>
```

So the value of the variable should be 24.

Comment: Please, add more explanation. It isn't clear why the expected result must be 24. I think the sum of the first three `hour` elements after the grouping is 16.

Comment: I make it 20; as far as I can tell, the first two should be grouped. However, if the 'Hour' element is summed when grouping, then it would be 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your requirement correctly, I think this should do the job:

```
<xsl:key name="countHours" match="Line" use="concat(EmpId,'-',Date)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(
    Records/Line[
      count(
        preceding-sibling::*[
          generate-id()=generate-id(key('countHours',concat(EmpId,'-',Date))[1])
        ]
      ) &lt; 3
    ]/Hour
  )" />
</xsl:template>
```